# How to assign array to array variable which is store in a database

Tags: php, arrays, database

I store array structure in database table.

**example**

```
table name - example
id=1
data= array("Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"43")
```

I want to get that array structure from table and assign data column to an array.

Example

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $table=$row['data'];
}
```

I did this way.. but it's not working. 
It results in:

```
$table[0]=>array("Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"43")
```

Comment: `$table[YOUR_ID_HERE] = YOUR_DATA;`

Comment: `$table=$row['data'][0];`

Answer (score 0):

You can save array data to database field in multiple ways.

I suggest two ways:

**1) Serialized array:**

you can save data using serialize() function.

```
e.g. $arr = array('234' => 'asfdads', 'asdf' => 'asdf2');
$toDb = addslashes(serialize($arr));

And then you can unserialize() them to get it back like:

$toDb = unserialize(stripslashes($fromDb));
```

**2) Using json_encode() and json_decode();**

```
e.g. $arr = array('234' => 'asfdads', 'asdf' => 'asdf2');
$toDb = json_encode($arr);

And then you can json_decode() them to get it back like:

$toDb = json_decode($fromDb)
```